# jquery jspdf cellInitialize is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I am using jsPDF for creating PDF from HTML. There are multiple table in my HTML. I want to show PDF in table's format as it is showing in HTML. Here is script which i am using

```
<script>
    $(function(){
         var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

   $('#cmd').click(function () {

        var table = tableToJson($('.table').get(0))
        var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt', 'a4', true);
        doc.cellInitialize();
        $.each(table, function (i, row){
            console.debug(row);
            $.each(row, function (j, cell){
                doc.cell(10, 50,120, 50, cell, i);  // 2nd parameter=top margin,1st=left margin 3rd=row cell width 4th=Row height
            })
        })


        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
    function tableToJson(table) {
    var data = [];

    // first row needs to be headers
    var headers = [];
    for (var i=0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi,'');
    }


    // go through cells
    for (var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++) {

        var tableRow = table.rows[i];
        var rowData = {};

        for (var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length; j++) {

            rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;

        }

        data.push(rowData);
    }       

    return data;
}
});
</script>
```

But when i execute it given error 
doc.cellInitialize() is not a function.

Any help why it is given error?

Thanks